# SwiftUI - How to position Images with NavigationLink

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui-navigationview

I'm trying to make a converter app using SwiftUI. I added navigationlinks on the Home Screen these buttons go to the right places,no problem until here. However, I couldn't position it.

Currently, when I position them with .position, they appear in different places on different devices.

How should I do the positioning here?
I want to provide an image that will be the same on all devices as in the screenshot.

Thanks for your help.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
    
        
        
        NavigationView{
            VStack() {
                
                
                // WEIGHT * MASS
                NavigationLink(destination: UnitView()) {
                Image(systemName: "scalemass")
                    .font(.system(size: 60))
                    .padding()
                    .frame(width: 150, height: 150, alignment: .center)
                    .background(Rectangle().fill(Color.purple.opacity(0.5))
                    .shadow(radius: 3)).cornerRadius(20)
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                    .overlay(Text("Mass")
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                        .padding()
                        .font(.system(size: 22)),
                             alignment: .bottom )}
                    .position(x:110, y:100)
                
                
                 //DISTANCE * 
                NavigationLink(destination: DistanceView()) {
                    Image(systemName: "figure.walk")
                        .font(.system(size: 60))
                        .padding()
                        .frame(width: 150, height: 150, alignment: .center)
                        .background(Rectangle().fill(Color.orange.opacity(0.5))
                        .shadow(radius: 3)).cornerRadius(20)
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                        .overlay(Text("Distance")
                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                            .padding()
                            .font(.system(size: 22)),
                                 alignment: .bottom )}
                        .position(x:110, y:100)
                
                    
                    //TEMPERATURE * 
                    NavigationLink(destination: TemperatureView()) {
                        Image(systemName: "thermometer.sun")
                            .font(.system(size: 56))
                            .padding()
                            .frame(width: 150, height: 150, alignment: .center)
                            .background(Rectangle().fill(Color.yellow.opacity(0.5))
                            .shadow(radius: 3)).cornerRadius(20)
                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                            .overlay(Text("Temperature")
                                .foregroundColor(.black)
                                .padding()
                                .font(.system(size: 21)),
                                     alignment: .bottom )}
                            .position(x:280, y:-84)
                        
                    // TIME * 
                    NavigationLink(destination: TimeView()) {
                        Image(systemName: "clock")
                            .font(.system(size: 60))
                            .padding()
                            .frame(width: 150, height: 150, alignment: .center)
                            .background(Rectangle().fill(Color.blue.opacity(0.5))
                            .shadow(radius: 3)).cornerRadius(20)
                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                            .overlay(Text("Time")
                                .foregroundColor(.black)
                                .padding()
                                .font(.system(size: 21)),
                                     alignment: .bottom ) }
                            .position(x:280, y:-444)
            
        
                    }
                 }
             }
         }
    
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
       static var previews: some View {
           ContentView()
       }
    }
```

[Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8paHa.png)

Comment: Are you *sure* you want to absolutely position and use the same frames for all devices? This goes against the standard practice of adapting to fit different screen sizes, which SwiftUI is particularly suited for.

Answer (score 0):

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Image("example-image")
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                    .cornerRadius(10)
                
                NavigationLink(destination: DetailView()) {
                    Text("View Details")
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .padding()
                        .background(Color.blue)
                        .cornerRadius(10)
                }
                .padding(.top, 20)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct DetailView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Details View")
    }
}
```

In this example, we use a `VStack` to position an image and a `NavigationLink`. The image is resized to **100x100** and given a corner radius of 10 using the `.frame` and `.cornerRadius` modifiers. The `NavigationLink` leads to a `DetailView` that simply displays the text "Details View". The text inside the `NavigationLink` is styled to have white foreground color, padding, a blue background color, and a corner radius of 10. The `.padding(.top, 20)` adds some space between the image and the link.

Comment: Hello,

I think there is a misunderstanding.

I don't have a problem with my images, I just can't locate them on the screen.

I want to align the images I created as in the screenshot, but when I do this with .position they appear in very different places on different devices.

I am attaching the screenshot again.

How do I position it to look like this on all devices?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8paHa.png